# The image in a slider does not link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with wow slider that is I can not link an image .
even though it shows the link address but it is not working when the image is clicked.
I use an `href` tag before `img` tag  but this link does not work.

How can I use `href` tag in this slider?
Here is my snippet :

CSS Code :

```
#wowslider-container1 {
    display: table;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px;
    z-index: 90;
    text-align: left; /* reset align=center */
    font-size: 10px;
    text-shadow: none; /* fix some user styles */
    /* reset box-sizing (to boostrap friendly) */
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
* html #wowslider-container1 {
    width: 1920px
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 10000%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    overflow: visible;/*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul li {
    position: relative;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 0; /*opera*/
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    /*font-size:0;*/
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    display: block;
    color: transparent;
}
#wowslider-container1 img {
    max-width: none !important;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images .ws_list img, #wowslider-container1 .ws_images > div > img {
    width: 100%;
    border: none 0;
    max-width: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images > div > img {
    max-height: 600px;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images iframe {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title > div {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
#wowslider-container1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 70;
}


/* hide controls when video start play */
#wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_bullets, #wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_fullscreen, #wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_next, #wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_prev {
    display: none;
}
/* youtube/vimeo buttons */
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 55;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_youtube, #wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_vimeo {
    display: block;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn div {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(./playvideo.png);
    background-size: 200%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 7em;
    height: 5em;
    margin-left: -3.5em;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_youtube div {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_youtube:hover div {
    background-position: 100% 0;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_vimeo div {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_vimeo:hover div {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause.ws_hide {
    display: none !important;
}
/* bullets */
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a.ws_selbull {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
/* arrows */
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next, #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    position: absolute;
    font: 3.2em "ws-ctrl-bootstrap";
    z-index: 60;
    color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: .5;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next {
    left: 85%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    left: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next:after, #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next:after {
    content: '\e801';
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev:after {
    content: '\e800';
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next:hover, #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
/*playpause*/
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause {
    position: absolute;
    font: 3.2em "ws-ctrl-bootstrap";
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.3125em;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 59;
    display:none
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause:after {
    display: block;

    text-align: center;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_pause:after {
    content: '\e803';
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_play:after {
    content: '\e802';
}/* bottom center */
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets div {
    left: -50%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid #ffffff;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    left: 77px;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title {
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    font: 2.4em 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 50px;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 50;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title div {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.542em;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images > ul {
    animation: wsBasic 12s infinite;
    -moz-animation: wsBasic 12s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: wsBasic 12s infinite;
}
@keyframes wsBasic {
0% {
left:-0%
}
16.67% {
left:-0%
}
33.33% {
left:-100%
}
50% {
left:-100%
}
66.67% {
left:-200%
}
83.33% {
left:-200%
}
}
@-moz-keyframes wsBasic {
0% {
left:-0%
}
16.67% {
left:-0%
}
33.33% {
left:-100%
}
50% {
left:-100%
}
66.67% {
left:-200%
}
83.33% {
left:-200%
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes wsBasic {
0% {
left:-0%
}
16.67% {
left:-0%
}
33.33% {
left:-100%
}
50% {
left:-100%
}
66.67% {
left:-200%
}
83.33% {
left:-200%
}
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a img {
    text-indent: 0;
    display: block;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: -77px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    max-width: none;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a:hover img {
    visibility: visible;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div div {
    height: 48px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div {
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 153px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets .ws_bulframe {
    display: none;
    bottom: 19px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div div {
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ariafarparvaz.com/js/wowslider.js"></script> 


<div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://www.ariafarparvaz.com/images/slide2.jpg" alt="bootstrap carousel" title="slide2" id="wows1_1"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ws_bullets">
        <div> <a href="" title="slide1"><span></span></a> <a href="#" title="slide2"><span></span></a> <a href="#" title="slide4"><span></span></a> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: When testing it in Chrome and clicking on the image for slide two, it takes me to Yahoo.  Maybe the issue isn't with the link?  Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: All looks good to go here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xn6KL/2/

Comment: @wpalmesyeah i've already tested . it's not work in chrome.

Comment: @DanielD where shoud i put this jquery code?

Comment: @wpalmes i'm using chrome

Comment: I ran it straight with the code you provided putting the script tags in the head and it ran fine... cache issue?

Comment: @inaz that plugin code would have to go inside of your js file or script tag on your page. Additionally I'm sure you could just find the wowslider CDN and use that also. To give a better reference, check out this page. Click on the demo and view the page source and you'll get an idea of how you can hook this up on your site.